# HTML5 PHP Form issue

Tags: php, html, web, webforms

I am 15 and new to HTML and PHP so if i did something stupid, please excuse me!

I have made a website with a contact form and I made the .php file. This is my code:

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="contact.php">
```

I click submit and it takes my to the contact.php file and it shows me the code in the browser. How do I make the php file actually work?

Comment: could you post all the code please? and what do you want to do? store in a database or email?

Comment: Is PHP actually supported by your server?

Comment: you should also check that short tags are not used, e.g <? for opening and also <?= as if its set to off your also see un-parsed  code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is neither PHP nor HTML (much less HTML5) -- if a PHP file displays in the browser, then webserver is not set up right. However, without knowing what machine you are on , it's impossible to advise further.

Also, welcome to web programming, we are here to help. Please consider contributing to an open source project (I would recommend Drupal of course :) ).

Answer (score 3):

There are two suspects here.

1).  You're trying to view this locally.  You'll need to actually have a server with PHP installed and route things through that.

2).  Your server doesn't understand PHP.

---

Added:

Actually a 3rd thought occurred to me:

3).  Your PHP file doesn't have a PHP start marker set.  Make sure the file begins with `<?php` (although there are some derivations of that).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have installed server ? If you don't have, you can use [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) - includes apache, php, mysql and other stuff.